# Get null records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the next query:

```
    SELECT c.name as clientName, p.id as projectId, p.name as projectName, p.rate, u.name as userName, sum(w.duration) as workedHours
    FROM Project p, User u, Worklog w, Client c
    WHERE w.user_id = u.id AND w.project_id = p.id AND p.client_id = c.id
    GROUP BY p.id, u.id
```

that returns the projects, clients, hourly rate and worked hours.

How should be changed to return also the projects where `workedHours is equal with 0`?

Because this query returns just the records where `workedHours is not 0`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just use proper `left join`s, not that ancient `WHERE` monstrosity. Then the rows with no `Worklog` will have `null` in its fields.

Comment: Is this query even work, because in the GROPU BY there are only two columns, in the SELECT there are more than two?

Comment: @EminMesic yes it's working well (it returns all the records where it finds data) even without the 3rd condition for GROUP BY

Comment: @underscore_d thank you for info, don't really know much about left/right/inner join, but good point to start and learn them, thank you

Comment: @Emin Mesic: This is fine according to standard SQL. By grouping by user ID and project ID, we can savely select user and project data, such as names and rate. And as there is just one client per project, we can select the client data, too. This is called functional dependency. Some DBMS don't support this, though, and require that you add the data columns to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Vlad Popa: Comma-separated joins as you use them are really a relict from the 1980s. Explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.) made it into the SQL standard in 1992. So, yes, it's a good idea to learn them and stop using comma-separated joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that no row in worklog can be joined, and that your condition in the `WHERE` clause removes any row without worklog associated.

### Solution 1 : Using a LEFT JOIN

Using a left join instead would solve your problem.

```
SELECT c.name as clientName, p.id as projectId, p.name as projectName, p.rate, u.name as userName, coalesce(sum(w.duration), 0) as workedHours
FROM Project p, User u, Client c
LEFT JOIN Worklog w ON w.project_id = p.id AND w.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY p.id, u.id
```

By the way your query is suspicious in other aspects. For example c.name is in the SELECT clause but not in the GROUP BY clause. I take it that you use MySQL which is the only RDBMS I'm aware of which allows such queries. You maybe should consider adding the retrieved columns in the GROUP BY clause.

### Solution 2 : Using only ANSI JOINs

As underscore_d points out, you may want to avoid old-style joins completely, and preferable use the following query :

```
SELECT
  c.name as clientName,
  p.id as projectId,
  p.name as projectName,
  p.rate,
  u.name as userName,
  coalesce(sum(w.duration), 0) as workedHours
FROM Project p
CROSS JOIN User u
INNER JOIN Client c ON p.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Worklog w ON w.project_id = p.id AND w.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY c.name, p.id, p.name, p.rate, u.id, u.name
```

### Solution 3 - Using a subquery

Another solution is to use a subquery, which would allow you to remove the GROUP BY clause completely and get a more manageable query if you ever need to retrieve more information. I personally don't like long lists of columns in a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT
  c.name as clientName,
  p.id as projectId,
  p.name as projectName,
  p.rate,
  u.name as userName,
  (SELECT SUM(duration) FROM Worklog WHERE project_id = c.id AND user_id = u.id) as workedHours
FROM Project p
CROSS JOIN User u
INNER JOIN Client c ON p.client_id = p.id
```

Comment: Indeed, but we should also advise not to use `where` for inner joins too; use `inner join` instead. Using `where` to 'join' has been obsolete since, what, 1992?

Comment: I did not know it was deprecated. I thought it was just a matter of style. Anyway I added your suggestion to my answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @FabianPijcke I don't really know much about SQL, but the latest query you wrote it doesn't really return the records not even close as expected (but I don't really know why so I can't really point out where or if there's been a mistake). Also, thank you for your time

Comment: Indeed I wrote `p` instead of `c` :-) Let me fix this, you're very welcome! And thank you for your catch

Comment: @FabianPijcke Thank you, that second solution really worked for me, I didn't pay enough attention to tables alias and thought is about some join or something else. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @FabianPijcke I've got a question. If I try to add a `WHERE` clause like for `w.date BETWEEN dateA AND dateB` should be before `GROUP BY` or somewhere in a `JOIN` with `AND w.date BETWEEN dateA AND dateB` ?

Response for rookies like me: 
on this line `LEFT JOIN Worklog w ON w.project_id = p.id AND w.user_id = u.id` I've added the condition for date and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard ANSI joins and use `LEFT JOIN` on `worklog` table and ultimately you have to use `LEFT JOIN` on the `user` table as follows:

```
SELECT C.NAME   AS CLIENTNAME,
       P.ID     AS PROJECTID,
       P.NAME   AS PROJECTNAME,
       P.RATE,
       U.NAME   AS USERNAME,
       SUM(W.DURATION) AS WORKEDHOURS
  FROM PROJECT   P
  JOIN CLIENT    C
ON P.CLIENT_ID = C.ID
  LEFT JOIN WORKLOG   W
ON W.PROJECT_ID = P.ID
  LEFT JOIN USER      U
ON W.USER_ID = U.ID
 GROUP BY P.ID,
          U.ID;
```